# If and Else If instruction

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a directory with doc files (name firstname)

For example I have this:

Doe John.doc

Doe Phil.doc

Doe Robert.doc

Poe Dameron.doc

I have a listbox with all the persons from a database, I choose a name and I click ‘open file’

My piece of code :

```
       string fullname = Name + " " + Firstname; 

       string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles((Doc_Path));
       foreach (string file in allFiles)
       {
           if (file.Contains(fullname))
           {
               Process.Start(file);
               return;
           }
       // if it cant found fullname, try to open by Name only
           else if(file.Contains(Name)) 
           {
               Process.Start(file);
               return;
           }
       }
```

My  problem :

If I choose Doe Robert it opens Doe John in all case, but it should stop at the first IF instruction

I don't understand even if its the basic of basics :/

Comment: Look at what you're doing step by step: when your fullname is "Doe Robert" and current file is "Doe John" the first `if` statement will obviously fail, but the second one (`else if`) will not ("Doe John" contains "Doe"). In order to make your code work the way you want, see the answer by @PatrickHofman below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually want to do a exact match first and then a fuzzy match. You have to walk the `foreach` for a second time to check for your fuzzy match later:

```
foreach (string file in allFiles)
{
    if (file.Contains(fullname))
    {
        Process.Start(file);
        return;
    }
}

foreach (string file in allFiles)
{
    // if it cant found fullname, try to open by Name only
    if(file.Contains(Name)) 
    {
        Process.Start(file);
        return;
    }
}
```

The `return` causes the rest of the code not being executed on the first match found.

Comment: Then there is something with the name: additional spaces maybe.

Comment: Thanks, it works ,  I just found an issue : if file of Doe Phil doesn't exists, it will open Doe John, I try to block that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple linq statement for this:

```
string file = allFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Contains(fullname)) ??
              allFiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Contains(Name));
if (file != null) Process.Start(file);
```

This first `FirstOrDefault` searches `allFiles` for a file that contains `fullname`. If no such file is found, `null` is returned and the `??` operator executes the right part, searching `allFiles` for the first to contain `Name`.

Comment: It works, but I'll use the Patrick Hoffman solution because I'm not used with linq statement , Thanks anyway

Comment: @D.Iple That's fine, you should only use code you understand. But you may eventually take the time to dive into linq, because it's a powerful and elegant tool.